# what is the difference between DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT and Global Concurrent Dispatch Queues

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) in the apple documentation that for creating concurrent queues both DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT and Global Concurrent Dispatch Queues can be used however I am uncertain as to what the difference between the two is.

E.x.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ });
```

and

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("custom",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{ });
```

I read something on barriers but not sure how it comes into the picture in relationship with these two. Can anybody please explain the use cases for both of these ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four global concurrent queues, one for each of four different priorities, that always exist and that are always there if you need them. So you don't have to create a concurrent queue to execute some block in the background. dispatch_get_global_queue () returns one of these four queues.

You can, if you want, create your own queues and delete them when you don't need them anymore.

What you are reading about barriers: The global queues are used by *everyone*. Using a barrier in a queue that is used by *everyone* is let's say highly impolite. That's why you shouldn't use barriers in global queues, only in queues that you created yourself.

Comment: Great point about "barriers." They *definitely* have no place in a global queue, and so, "any case where you're thinking that you need to use a barrier, a semaphore, etc." is probably a use-case for a non-global queue. That queue is, if you will, "purpose-specific," whereby you stuff a bunch of messages onto the queue with a barrier-entry in between them to set them apart ... and the readers/writers on that queue all understand what's going on with *that* queue. (And a global queue might be a place to stack a notification message: "hey guys, I just put something on queue-X. Go check it out.")

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are requesting one of the "global queues" which are provided for your application. "Anyone, anywhere, in your app" can get an easy reference to that queue just by asking `dispatch_get_global_queue()` for it.  The queues are, in effect, singletons.  And, *nearly all* of the time, that's all you need.  The OS helpfully builds them for you and makes them really easy for everybody (in your app) to get to.

`dispatch_queue_create()` is used in those rare times when you actually need "another queue." It's bound to your application just like all the other queues are, but you manage it yourself. You have to provide some means for other parts of your app to get that queue-handle. You might do this if, say, in your design it's *really* necessary for different kinds of requests to be placed onto different queues.

And, as I said, *most* of the time, the global queues are all you really need. (The OS makes them "really handy," and that's *why* they're "really handy.") Typically, you "put lots of messages on just a few queues," with a one-to-many or many-to-many or many-to-one relationship between readers and writers.